# Updating objects value when another class updates it

Tags: java

I have 3 classes.

```
Car.java
Garage.java
Driver.java
Race.java
```

So the situation I am in is that I currently have 3 separate classes that are looking and updating each other. The situation is that when `Garage` updates the `Car` attributes. Every `Car` also has assigned `Driver`. How would I be able to run `acknoweldgeNewTires()` if Cars attributes have been changed?

I have tried Observer and Observable, but apparently that it has been deprecated, so I am looking for an alternative.

My current code is here:

**Race.java**

```
public class Race {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Garage teamBlue = new Garage();
        Car blueCar = new Car();
        teamBlue.changeTires("Michelin");

    }
}
```

**Garage.java**

```
public class Garage {

    Car car;

    public void changeTires(String tire){
        Car.tiresBrand = tire;
    }
}
```

**Car.java**

```
public class Car {

    public static String tiresBrand = "Dunlop";
    public Driver driver;

    public Car(){

        driver = new Driver(this);
    }
}
```

**Driver.java**

```
public class Driver {

    public Car driversCar;

    public Driver(Car car){
        driversCar = car;
    }

    public void acknoweldgeNewTires(){
        System.out.println("New tires received!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @TheHeadRush I know this is not the greatest example I am trying to create a similar situation, because I cannot disclose the real code. And in this situation, it is okay to assume that there is only one car, driver, garage.

Answer (score 1):

1) Don't use `static` in `Car`. The tires are for a car, not any car.
2) To "intercept" this kinds of event, you should favor methods over `public` field access when you update the `Car` state.

You can use publisher/subscriber pattern to reduce the coupling between the classes but here it seems an overhead.

So in Garage you could do :

```
private Car car;
private List<Car> cars; // Or better because a single Car for a Garage is weird
public void changeTires(String tire){
    car.setTiresBrandAndNotifyDriver(tire);
}
```

And in Car :

```
public void setTiresBrandAndNotifyDriver(String tire){
   this.tire = tire;
   this.driver.acknoweldgeNewTires();
}
```

Comment: My goal was not to touch the Car.java, do you think it is possible to update Car that the driver has without running a continues Thread that updates Car object in Driver class?

Comment: All is possible but I cannot encourage you to do it in a twisted way.

Comment: @AndroidFreak When you use the same object reference the `Car` object gets updated "automatically" since it is the actual same object you are changing.